# What is meant by そこはね here?

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence

> 女：手でね、書かなくても、今パソコンで作るからさ、別に問題はないんだけど でも頭の中にあるものを手で書けたら、なんかもっと幅が広がるような気がして
> 男：これ、あれですね、ペンタブ買うやつですね
> 女：いや、まずはね・・・まずあの・・・そんなお金はかけない。紙からやるけど、上手になったら考える
> 男：偉いね！形から入るタイプの人だったらまず買うよ
> 女：いや、でもさ、紙で書けない人がペンタブなんか使いこなせるわけないじゃん **さすがにそこはね**
> 男：わからないよ

Does さすがにそこはね here mean that the reason she would buy the paper to draw on first is because you need to know how to draw by hand before using tablets and not because she is not whimsical and not superficial like the man said?
Also, what does she mean by 幅が広がるような気がして ?

Answer (score 1):

さすがにそこはね is often used to express the idea that even though the speaker (or somebody else) has done something negative or unfavorable, there's a certain limit or boundary they would not cross. It's a way to admit to a fault or negative aspect, while also emphasizing that there are still some lines they won't cross.

What she concretely means in this context is ambiguous IMO. It could mean "I might be prone to buying stuff to feel good (形から入る) but even I am not going as far as buying an (expensive) tablet before I'm good enough".

A more obvious example is: 「え、落とした財布拾ってあげたの？落とし主のことすごい嫌ってたのに？」「さすがにそこはね。いくら嫌いなやつでも財布落としてたら拾ってあげるよそこはさすがに」

Answer (score 0):

さすがにそこはね is just emphasizing her rationale for not buying a tablet when she is not even sure if she can draw on paper nicely while avoiding repetition. If I complete the sentence it would be something like さすがに使いこなせるかどうかもわからないタブレットにお金を払うことはできない。

幅が広がるような気がして means "it would broaden my horizon somehow"